# Allow all users to create folders in HDD, but only owners can read/write/delete their own folders

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 18, I have mounted an external drive in `/mnt/hdd/` and then I have changed its permission with `sudo chmod 777 /mnt/hdd/`. In this way, all users can write in this external HDD. However, in this way, if user A creates a folder, then user B can delete the folder created by user A. How can I avoid this? Ideally, every user should be able to write to `/mnt/hdd/`, but only the user that creates its folder should be able to write/delete it.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `777`. Use `chmod` and set the owner and group accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do:

`sudo chmod 1777 /mnt/hdd`

That's how /tmp works.

Comment: By the way, this is called the "sticky bit". It is also represented by `T`.